# How to restrict user to change the URL in PHP

Tags: php, url-routing

I would like to know that if there is a method in the controller which require arguments and the user changes the argument in the URL by hand, and presses enter it should display the default page. Below is my bootstrap, then I have already created a error controller for URL error. So please give some coding guide or if there is some thing in my code, change it. Thanks in advance.

```
<?php
    class App
    {
        protected $controller = 'indexController';
        protected $method = 'index';
        protected $params = array();
        public function __construct()
        {
            $url = $this->parseUrl();
            //print_r($url);
            if (isset($url[0]))
            {
                if (file_exists('app/controllers/'.$url[0].'.php'))
                {
                    $this->controller = $url[0];
                    unset($url[0]);

                }
                require_once('app/controllers/'.$this->controller.'.php');
                $this->controller = new $this->controller;
            }
            else 
                {
                    $error = new errorController();
                    $error->setError("Page Not Found");
                    echo $error->getError();
                }       

            if (isset($url[1]))
            {
                if (method_exists($this->controller,$url[1]))
                {
                    $this->method = $url[1];
                    unset($url[1]);
                }
                else
                {
                    $error = new errorController();
                    $error->setError("Page Not Found");
                    echo $error->getError();
                }

            }
            else
                {
                    $error = new errorController();
                    $error->setError("Page Not Found");
                    echo $error->getError();


                }

            $this->params = $url ? array_values($url) : array();
            call_user_func_array(array($this->controller,$this->method),$this->params);
        }
        public function parseUrl()
        {
            if (isset($_GET['url']))
            {
                return $url =explode('/',filter_var(rtrim($_GET['url'],'/'),FILTER_SANITIZE_URL));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Why do you worry about that?

Answer (score 1):

The method itself must check if the parameters provided are valid and throw an exception if not. Afterwards just catch the exception and trigger and error page to be displayed.

Comment: Thanks bro ur suggestion works.i have just added this code in my model class if ($result == false){ //require_once('app/controllers/errorController.php'); $error = new errorController(); $error->setError("Page not Found"); $error->randerError();

Answer (score 1):

Seems like you could use POST and $_POST, instead of GET.  Then it won't matter if the user includes or alters parameters because your PHP will ignore them.

Comment: i tried your suggestion this is also working , this is really good example of polymorphism :)